# Angular7 - How to use Observable and add attributes

Tags: observable, angular7

I would like to add an attribute to my Project Observable Object.
This attribute should be a random image from a random other project.
Like this we can navigate from project randomly.

I'm struggling to work with Observable in Angular 7

Project have multiple images and from project i would like to have a random image from other project.

data

```
const Project =[
  { id: 1, name: 'project1', imgs:['a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg']},
  { id: 2, name: 'project2', imgs:['e.jpg','f.jpg','h.jpg']},
  { id: 3, name: 'project3', imgs:['j.jpg','k.jpg','g.jpg']},
  { id: 4, name: 'project4', imgs:['v.jpg','x.jpg','y.jpg']},
  { id: 5, name: 'project5', imgs:['z.jpg','u.jpg','p.jpg']},
];
```

service

```
getProject(id: number): Observable<Project> {
  const url = `${this.projectUrl}/${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Project>(url).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError<Project>(`getProject id=${id}`))
  );
}
```

project.component

```
getProject(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.projecService.getProject(id)
        .subscribe(project => this.project = project);
}
```

project.component.html

i would like to have access to `{{project.randomImg}}`

--

I would like to add in getProject the name of a random image from another project by using `genRdm(max, id);`

```
genRdm(max, id):number {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  return (num === id ) ? this.generateRandom(1, max) : num;
}
```

example if i choose project1, i would like to choose randomly project2 or project3 with `genRdm(numberOfProject, currentProjectId)` and get a random image from it.

```
genRdm(5,1) ==> 2 (project2)
```

then choose random image from project2 and attach it to getProject (but I don't know how to do it)

```
genRdm(numbersOfImg,0) ==> example f.jpg
```

In project.component I would be able to have the chosen project with a random image from other project

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a working solution for my website, please share your thought.

project.service.ts

```
getRandomImg(id: number){
  var nId = this.generateRandom(5, id);
  const url = `${this.projectUrl}/${nId}`;
  return this.http.get<Project>(url);
}

generateRandom(max, id):number {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  return (num === id ) ? this.generateRandom(1, max) : num;
}
```

project.component.ts

```
ngOnInit():void{
    this.getProject();
}

getProject(): void {
    this.route.params.pipe(
        switchMap((params: Params) => this.projectService.getProject(+params['id']))
    )
    .subscribe(project => {
        this.project = project;
        this.projectService.getRandomImg(project.id)
        .subscribe(projectRnd =>{
            let rnd = this.projectService.generateRandom(projectRnd.imgs.length,0);
            this.randomImg = {projectShortname:projectRnd.shortname, projectId:projectRnd.id, path:rnd+'.jpg'};
         });
    });

}
```

but ideally the random stuff should be inside the getProject on server side but I don't know how to do this.